# Move ConEmu prompt to new line following path?

Tags: conemu

ConEmu by default has a prompt which is like "${cwdfull}>"  I'd like instead, "${cwdfull}\n> ".  How do I customize this?  I see it must be possible since cmdr which is based on ConEmu has it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConEmu by default

```
conemu -basic -cmd {cmd}
```

has following prompt

[image: ConEmu default prompt]

You can easily check how it is created in [Tasks](http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html) and [%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/blob/master/Release/ConEmu/CmdInit.cmd) batch file. All "magic" is done by `PROMPT` variable. For example `set PROMPT=$P$_$G`.

**Update**

I really do not understand your question from the comment below. Default ConEmu task {cmd (Admin)} has the same prompt and its configuration is done by absolutely the same way.

[image: ConEmu 'cmd (Admin)' prompt]

Comment: I marked it as answered, but prematurely!  I'm sure this is right, but how do I get a default task ({cmd} Admin) to do it?  I have other apps launching conemu for me some configurable, some not (for example ides and context menu os)

Comment: Ah, I had an older portable version conflicting via Path.  A few uninstallations and resets and I'm great now :)  Thanks a ton Maximus!  Honestly M$ owes you big time.