# In ConEmu is it possible to get the command prompt all in one line?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, conemu

Just started using conemu on windows again (after quite some time using other rubbish). Its great, but there is one element that really bugs me, that is the command prompt is always spread over two lines:

```
user.name@DESDAH181093 D:\user\workspace\
>
user.name@DESDAH181093 D:\user\workspace\
>
user.name@DESDAH181093 D:\user\workspace\
>
```

Can I get it so that this is compressed onto the same line, like this?

```
user.name@DESDAH181093 D:\user\workspace\>
user.name@DESDAH181093 D:\user\workspace\>
user.name@DESDAH181093 D:\user\workspace\>
```

I looked through the settings and did not spot anything obvious.

I saw this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126044/move-conemu-prompt-to-new-line-following-path), but I think I want to do the opposite and I can't find where anything like `${cwdfull}\n>` is defined in the settings...

**UPDATE**

In addition to the answer of Max, here is what I really needed to change in the CmdInit.cmd file:

```
rem Carriage return and `$` or `>`
rem Spare `$E[90m` was specially added because of GitShowBranch.cmd
if "%ConEmuIsAdmin%" == "ADMIN" (
  set ConEmuPrompt2=$S$E[90m$$
) else (
  set ConEmuPrompt2=$S$E[90m$G
)
```

Where both ConEmuPrompt2 where:

```
ConEmuPrompt2=$_$E[90m$$
changed here   ^
```

Comment: The answer from the link does not contain any mentions of `cwdfull`. Consider, yours is the duplicate.

Comment: I am sure its not a duplicate... the answer does not describe the changes I need to make. However they do hint at it. Also your answer must be for an older version of ConEmu or something? - anyway it got me where I needed to get, so +1's all around. I have posted an update to my question to clarify your answer....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make a copy of `ConEmu\CmdInit.cmd` file.
2. Replace I the copied file `$_` with `$S`, save changes )
3. Utilize your modified file in the task `{Shells::cmd}`.
4. Save ConEmu settings.